# How do you customise the okta application loading screen?

Tags: okta

How do you customise the okta application loading screen?

This is the screen after you've signed into Okta, which is displayed when accessing an application.
It looks like a bar of grey, with a group of circles that spin.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is possible using the `interstitialUrl`. The `interstitialUrl` points to a custom page embedded inside an `iframe`. Modifying it allows you to use any page/style of your choosing.

Here are the requirements to creating the custom page:

- Page must be HTTPS
- Page is rendered inside an iframe
- Host the `interstitialUrl` and the URL inside the `iframe`

However, use CAUTION when updating the contents of your organization.

Step 1: (Requires [API Token](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/getting_a_token.html))

```
GET https://{{subdomain}}.okta.com/api/v1/orgs/{{subdomain}}
```

**Edit** the JSON from the response, changing only the `interstitialUrl`:

```
  "settings": {
      "app": {
        "interstitialUrl": "https://example.com/interstitial.html",
        ...
      },
      ...
  }
```

Step 2: Submit a `PUT` request (Requires [API Token](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/getting_a_token.html))

```
PUT https://{{subdomain}}.okta.com/api/v1/orgs/{{subdomain}}
```

Use the **updated** JSON from **Step 1** as the request body.

> **Edit (1/30/2019)**
>
> This isn't a feature that is supported and can be removed at Okta's discretion. Please use at your own risk and do not expect this functionality to exist in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I raise a suppose case with Okta, and the feedback I received was this is not currently possible.

"We do at this time provide customisations for the sign in page in Okta and greater customisation capabilities if using the Okta sign in Widget however none of these extend to the loading page for the applications. "

Answer (score 0):

To customize Okta application loading screen, please follow below steps:

1. Login to your Okta organization
2. Go to Admin tab
3. Click on Setting
4. From Setting drop down menu select Appearance, here you can configure Application Theme, Sign-in configuration, organization logo.

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to update `interstitialUrl` using the Okta REST API.

```json
{
    "errorCode": "E0000001",
    "errorSummary": "Api validation failed: updateOrg",
    "errorLink": "E0000001",
    "errorId": "oae2uOlYhZyQwy2smOyFQecLA",
    "errorCauses": [
        {
            "errorSummary": "Interstitial page URL cannot be modified."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Its not an answer to the question above